# Can a django url contain a fixed path at the beginning?

Tags: python, django, server, apache2, django-urls

I have a server running a django application. This version is stable.
For testing purposes I want to host a testing version of the same application on the server in **parallel**. Both applications have the similar views.

Normally you could do this with subdomains, so the stable version runs at `myserver.de` and the testing version at `test.myserver.de`. This is not possible for me, I have only one available domain (`myserver.de`).

So I can only use paths. Let's say I host the stable version at `myserver.de/[apps urls]` and the test version at `myserver.de/test/[apps urls]`.
To achieve this, i could edit all urls in the testing version. But that would defeat the purpose of testing, because to then make a testing version stable, i would have to re-edit all urls.

So I would like to simply edit `settings.py` and put `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["mysite.de/test"]` for the testing version. I tested this locally with `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1:8000/test", "127.0.0.1/test"]`, but that unsurprisingly didn't work (I read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) ^^)

Is there a way to run two applications on a django server where the urls of one app always start with `/test/<rest>` without editing all urls?
Could I do this with apache2 instead? (My guess was no, because django builds all links in the templates, so it must know about being "inside" `/test`.

Comment: I have edited my answer please check if it is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

How about just including the urls like so:

```
stable_urls = [
    ...
]
testing_urls = [
    ...
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(stable_urls)),
    path('test/', include(testing_urls)),
]
```

Then later you could simply rename, when you want to change versions.
Edit: If I understand your problem correctly then you can do something like this have an empty app (django app) which is the main app of the django project. Now in this apps urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app_version_stable.urls')),
    path('test/', include('app_version_testing.urls')),
]
```

Comment: I just edited my question, maybe it wasn't clear, that both apps have identical urls. Also I want to host them in parallel. But I like your Idea with a list. I could simply comment out the "wrong" urls in urlpatterns.

I don't really understand what you mean by simply renaming.

Comment: If they have the same urls how are you testing? Do you not need to change the views? Anyway you can include the same list twice if needed just with different paths at the start. By renaming I meant renaming the lists.

Comment: I still don't really understand. I want to host both apps in parallel on the same server. But with your setup above wouldn't both applications claim the same urls? So i would need to disable the respective urls on the respective version, by commenting them out.

Comment: Do you mean you have two versions of the same app and you want to host them on the same server?

Comment: Jup thats right. Of course the testing version will have some minor changes, but nothing huge. I don't know, if I could explain well enough, how I want my setup to look like. But your approach almost works for me now.
I dont want to have an empty django app but instead I will have two apache virtualhosts. They will then take care to send the request to the right app, so clashing will not occur of course